# Disable Zend Developer Tools

Tags: php, zend-framework2

How can I disable ZF2 developer tools in a particular controller?

I've already tried returning an terminal ViewModel, but it still renders.

Comment: why dont you just disable them in your application.config.php in your config folder?

Comment: I don't want to disable it globally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create your own listener that fires before the zdt logic that detaches the events based on a specific controller.

```
<?php
namespace Application\Listener;

use Zend\EventManager\AbstractListenerAggregate;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class DetachZdtListener extends AbstractListenerAggregate
{

    protected $listeners = array();

    protected $serviceLocator;

    public function __construct(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $this->serviceLocator = $serviceLocator;
    }

    public function attach(\Zend\EventManager\EventManagerInterface $events)
    {
        // Attach a listener to the finish event that has a priority sooner
        // than the ZDT listener(s)
        $this->listeners[] = $events->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_FINISH,
            array($this, 'onFinish'), -9499
        );

    }

    /**
     * The method called when event is fired
     *
     * @param \Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent $e
     */
    public function onFinish(MvcEvent $e) {

        $controller = $e->getController();

        if ($controller === 'Application\Controller\SomeController') {

            $sm = $this->serviceLocator;

            $eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
            $sharedEventManager = $eventManager->getSharedManager();

            $eventManager->detachAggregate($sm->get('ZendDeveloperTools\FlushListener'));
            $eventManager->detachAggregate($sm->get('ZendDeveloperTools\ProfilerListener'));

            $sharedEventManager->clearListeners('profiler');
        }
    }

}
```

Then you would just need to attach this listener in the onBootstrap method of one fo your modules, and it should do what you're looking for.